# Is there a way to set a type's attribute to a default value?

Tags: basic4android

type raygun( currentCharge as int, maxDamage as int, minDamage as int)

I couldn't find any examples demonstrating how to set the type's attribute to a default value when it is initialized.  For example in this instance it would make sense to default the currentCharge to 100.  I understand constants aren't supported at the moment, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this that I may not have considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no automatic way to do it. 
You can however create a sub that will create the type and initialize it as required:

```
Dim rg As Raygun
rg = InitRaygun

Sub InitRaygun As Raygun
 Dim r As Raygun
 r.Initialize
 r.currentCharge = 100
 Return r
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I have been doing.  I wasn't sure if I had been missing something.  I have worked with languages that allowed something similar to Type raygun(currentCharge =100, maxDamage as int, minDamage as int).  I just wasn't certain if it could be done here.